# I need to sort rows in a spreadsheet based on the value in a column and always have them sort to the top

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie at coding and need some help! I want this to sort my rows in BOMsht always to the top based on if there is a quantity chosen or not.

I have tried sorting the rows based on the columns with the code below but it will leave black rows still. I want it to all sort from top to bottom without black rows.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pleasepleasework()

Dim i As Long, g As Long, h As Long, j As Long
Dim MediaSht As Worksheet, BOMSht As Worksheet
Dim row As Range

' set the worksheet objects
Set MediaSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Media")
Set BOMSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bill of Materials")

g = 6
h = 4
With MediaSht
    For i = 4 To 1000
        If .Range("A" & i).Value >= 1 Then
            BOMSht.Range("A" & g) = MediaSht.Range("A" & h)
            BOMSht.Range("B" & g) = MediaSht.Range("B" & h)
            BOMSht.Range("C" & g) = MediaSht.Range("C" & h)
            BOMSht.Range("D" & g) = MediaSht.Range("D" & h)
            BOMSht.Range("E" & g) = MediaSht.Range("E" & h)
            BOMSht.Range("F" & g) = MediaSht.Range("F" & h)
            Else
            BOMSht.Range("A" & g).ClearContents
            BOMSht.Range("B" & g).ClearContents
            BOMSht.Range("C" & g).ClearContents
            BOMSht.Range("D" & g).ClearContents
            BOMSht.Range("E" & g).ClearContents
            BOMSht.Range("F" & g).ClearContents
        End If
        g = g + 1
        h = h + 1
    Next i
End With

BOMSht.Range("G5") = "Index"
BOMSht.Columns("A:G").Sort key1:=Range("G6"), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

I want it to stop skipping the empty rows and delete them so that there are rows sorted from the top.

Comment: Is BOMSht empty when this code runs?  Does it have a formula in ColG?  It's not so clear exactly what is going on between these two sheets.

Comment: The BOMSht copies the rows over from the Mediasht when a quantity is added to the Mediasht Range or Else the contents on the BomSht are cleared

Comment: What is on BOMsht before the code runs though?  Is it empty except for headers or?  What is in ColG that you're sorting on?

Comment: No the BOMsht will have the copied over cells from the Mediasht before being sorted. Column G will be sorted on numbers

Comment: But there's no content in ColG?

Comment: I just realized that I didn't have the Range G coded in and when I added it it sorted to the top. How do I make it sort to just the top of row 6? It is sorting to row 2?

Comment: `BOMSht.Range("A5:G1000").Sort key1:=BOMSht.Range("G6"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes`

Comment: Thank you so much!